# how to get breaks and white spaces from database in react js using laravel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, textarea

hello to stack overflow,

I'm getting problem to get text as I save from textarea to database.

like this breaks and space, how will i get in this formate text from database
thanks for help and educating

below is frontend code for text area.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <textarea
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    style={{
    height: "200px",
    textAlign: "start!important",
    }}
    onChange={(e) => setPdesc(e.target.value)}
    id="pdesc"
    value={pdesc}
    placeholder="Write description"
   ></textarea>
 </div>
```

Here is the image

[image]

```
<div className="row mt-1 grid blog-details">
          {Object.keys(indexAll).length > 0 ? (
            indexAll.map((v) => (
          <div className="col-md-4 blog-details-more">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="post" />
                <h2>{v.ptitle}</h2>
                <p>{v.pdesc}</p>
                </div>
              ))
            ) : (
              <></>
            )}
        </div>
```

how it shows

[image]

want to show like

[image]

Comment: That is depend on how you store your data, format of your text in db and the way you fetch and show the data. please complete your question with sample codes and expected and current result. that will help people who want to answer.

Comment: updated the question with code and image please see again.

Answer (score 0):

U can use a textarea on frontend, for example:

```
<textarea className='form-control' rows={16} value={code} onChange={(e) => setCode(e.target.value)} />
```

And longtext on laravel's migration:

```
$table->longText('code');
```

Then u can show the text exactly how it was written using the [pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag

```
<pre>{db_response.code}</pre>
```